# JavaScriptで、URLの「status/」以降を取得したい

Tags: javascript

URLで「status/」以降の「空白」か「？」までを取得するにはどう書けばよいですか？

URL例
https://twitter.com/jaStackOverflow/status/1516703227395428359
https://twitter.com/StackOverflow/status/1372188139821932547
https://twitter.com/jaStackOverflow/status/1516703227395428359?hoge
https://twitter.com/StackOverflow/status/1372188139821932547?hoge

取得したい例
1516703227395428359
1372188139821932547
1516703227395428359
1372188139821932547

```
var url = new URL('https://twitter.com/jaStackOverflow/status/1516703227395428359');
var result = url.ここを知りたい;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

質問で要求されているとおりの答えではありませんが、このやり方は多分課題に対するより簡潔でベターなソリューションだと思います。

```
result = url.pathname.split('/').pop();
```